# order of elements order of group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Quoting: "Suppose that G is a finite group with an element p of order 5 and an element h of order 7. Why must $|G| \geq 35$? "

This question comes right after introducing Coset, Lagrange theorem, Euler and Fermat theorem.

Here is My approach and understanding:

let's have p ∈ P and h∈H where P and H are subgroups of G. 
As p is of order $5 \Longrightarrow P=\{p,p^2,p^3,p^4,p^5=e\}$. 
Similarly, as h if of order $7 \Longrightarrow H=\{h,h^2,...,h^7=e\}$

H and P are subgroups of G of their own right by definition, and P has to be a subgroup of H. Therefore, G⊃H⊃P.

Using Corollary of Lagrange theorem: "Let H and P be subgroups of a finite group G such that G ⊃ H ⊃ P. Then [G : P] = [G : H][H : P] "

And that " as [G:P] is the partition corresponding to the disjoint union of left coset", the |P| has to divide **evenly** |G|.

As 35 is the lowest common multiple of 5 and 7,
if |G| < 35, then either P or H won't be able to partition evenly G. ;
if |G| = 35, then both P and H do partition evenly G
if |G| > A  and that A ={common multiples of 5 and 7} then H and H do partition G.

Therefore $|G| \geq 35$

Any comment or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math on MSE see 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made one mistake: $P$ does not necessarily need to be in $H$. Take the integers modulo 35 under addition, then consider the subgroups $\{\overline0, \overline7,\overline{14},\overline{21},\overline{28}\}$ and $\{\overline0, \overline5,\overline{10},\overline{15},\overline{20},\overline{25},\overline{30}\}$. They are generated by $\overline{7}$ and $\overline{5}$ respectively, and generate all integers modulo 35. But clearly one is not contained in the other.

The proof you need comes directly from Lagrange's Theorem: the order of a subgroup always divides the order of the group. Since you have a subgroup of order 5 and a subgroup of order 7, then both orders must divide $|G|$.

Comment: thank you for the correction

Comment: If you liked it please accept the answer, so there's closure in that question. If not, please specify what you still have doubts about. :)